# Python always returning False in the boolean comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

this is my code. whatever I input for A and B it always returns false..

```
def TorF():
    for i in range(10):
        A = input('A: ')
        B = input('B: ')
        print((A and not B) or (B and not A))

TorF()
```

results:

```
>>> 
A: True
B: False
False
A: True
B: True
False
A: False
B: True
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.X, `input` returns a string, so you aren't actually performing your boolean logic on bools. It's always evaluating as `False` because `not s` is `False` for any non-empty string `s`; `s and False` is `False` for any value of `s`; and of course `False or False` is `False`. Try explicitly converting the type of A and B beforehand.

```
def TorF():
    for i in range(10):
        A = input('A: ').lower() == "true"
        B = input('B: ').lower() == "true"
        print((A and not B) or (B and not A))

TorF()
```

Result:

```
A: True
B: False
True
A: True
B: True
False
A: False
B: True
True
```

Comment: You could also consider using `ast.literal_eval()` here; it'll accept `True` and `False` literal strings, returning booleans.

Comment: where should i import the ast from? i got an error saying name 'ast' is not defined.

Comment: Did you do `import ast` beforehand?